# validation of excel sheet in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4

how to validate the heading names of excel sheet for both .XLS and .XLSX files 
    and count the number of columns present that have the heading names in excel using ruby on rails.

Comment: In which way you access the file? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) gem for this.

```
require 'roo'

expected_headers = %w[name city age]
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new('./your_file.xlsx').sheet('your sheet')
headers = xlsx.row(1)

expected_headers & headers
```